# Why the actual CPU utilization percentage exceeds Pod CPU limit in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I am running a few kubernetes pods in my a cluster (10 node). Each pod contains only one container which hosts one working process. I have specified the CPU "limits" and "requests" for the container . The following is a description of one pod that is running on a node (crypt12).

```
Name:           alexnet-worker-6-9954df99c-p7tx5
Namespace:      default
Node:           crypt12/172.16.28.136
Start Time:     Sun, 15 Jul 2018 22:26:57 -0400
Labels:         job=worker
                name=alexnet
                pod-template-hash=551089557
                task=6
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.38.0.1
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/alexnet-worker-6-9954df99c
Containers:
  alexnet-v1-container:
    Container ID:  docker://214e30e87ed4a7240e13e764200a260a883ea4550a1b5d09d29ed827e7b57074
    Image:         alexnet-tf150-py3:v1
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:4f18b4c45a07d639643d7aa61b06bfee1235637a50df30661466688ab2fd4e6d
    Port:          5000/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      /usr/bin/python3
      cifar10_distributed.py
    Args:
      --data_dir=xxxx

    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 15 Jul 2018 22:26:59 -0400
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     800m
      memory:  6G
    Requests:
      cpu:        800m
      memory:     6G
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-hfnlp (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-hfnlp:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-hfnlp
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/hostname=crypt12
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

The following is the output when I run "kubectl describle node crypt12"

```
Name:               crypt12
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=crypt12
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket=/var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 11 Jul 2018 23:07:41 -0400
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  OutOfDisk        False   Mon, 16 Jul 2018 16:25:43 -0400   Wed, 11 Jul 2018 22:57:22 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure   False   Mon, 16 Jul 2018 16:25:43 -0400   Wed, 11 Jul 2018 22:57:22 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Mon, 16 Jul 2018 16:25:43 -0400   Wed, 11 Jul 2018 22:57:22 -0400   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Mon, 16 Jul 2018 16:25:43 -0400   Wed, 11 Jul 2018 22:57:22 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Mon, 16 Jul 2018 16:25:43 -0400   Wed, 11 Jul 2018 22:57:42 -0400   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  172.16.28.136
  Hostname:    crypt12
Capacity:
 cpu:                8
 ephemeral-storage:  144937600Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             8161308Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                8
 ephemeral-storage:  133574491939
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             8058908Ki
 pods:               110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 f0444e00ba2ed20e5314e6bc5b0f0f60
 System UUID:                37353035-3836-5355-4530-32394E44414D
 Boot ID:                    cf2a9daf-c959-4c7e-be61-5e44a44670c4
 Kernel Version:             4.4.0-87-generic
 OS Image:                   Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://1.13.1
 Kubelet Version:            v1.11.0
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.11.0
Non-terminated Pods:         (3 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                                CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                                ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  default                    alexnet-worker-6-9954df99c-p7tx5    800m (10%)    800m (10%)  6G (72%)         6G (72%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-7kdkd                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                weave-net-dpclj                     20m (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource  Requests    Limits
  --------  --------    ------
  cpu       820m (10%)  800m (10%)
  memory    6G (72%)    6G (72%)
Events:     <none>
```

As showed, in the node description ("Non-terminated Pods" section), the CPU limits is 10%. However, when I run "ps" or "top" command on the node(crypt12), the CPU utilization of the working process exceeds 10% (about 20%). Why this happened?  Could anyone shed light on this? 
 [image]

UPDATED:
I found a github issue discussion where I found the answer of my question: the cpu percentage from "kubectl describe node" is "CPU-limits/# of Cores". Since I set CPU-limit to 0.8,  10% is the result of 0.8/8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a github issue discussion where I found the answer of my question: the cpu percentage from "kubectl describe node" is "CPU-limits/# of Cores". Since I set CPU-limit to 0.8,  10% is the result of 0.8/8.
Here is link: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24925

Comment: This much is clear. However this is not an answer to your own question. Your initial question was not why 800m is 10% of 8 cores, but how cpu utilisation in top exceeds 10%.

Comment: @webber Never mind maybe my question is not clear enough.  My initial question is why the actual utilization exceed 10% (10% is shown as the result of "kubectl describe nodes"  in Non-terminated Pods section). In Non-terminated Pods section, the CPU percentage has a different meaning than that from "top/ps". This is why I have had such confusion and asked the question. The following explanation does make sense to me

Comment: --continue-- " I think maybe you are talking about the % that is shown in kubectl describe node foo.

XXX% is not an acceptable format for CPU in a pod spec.

It is shown as a convenience in kubectl describe nodes. In that case, percent-cpu = pod-request-or-limit/node-capacity 
So a node with capacity 2 , with pod with request 100m has request of 0.100 / 2 = 0.05 = 5% "

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, by default, Top shows percentage utilisation per core. so with 8 cores you can have 800% ultilisation.

If you're reading the top statistics right then it might have something to do with fact that your node is running more processes than just your pod. Think kube-proxy, kubelet and any other controllers. GKE also runs a dashboard and calls the api for statistics.

Also note that resources are calculated per 100ms. A container can spike above the 10 percent utilisation, but on average never use more than allowed within this duration.

In the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run) it reads:

> The spec.containers[].resources.limits.cpu is converted to its millicore value and multiplied by 100. The resulting value is the total amount of CPU time that a container can use every 100ms. A container cannot use more than its share of CPU time during this interval.

Comment: I understand the that I can have 800% utilization. However, I am still confused. The CPU limit of a pod is 10%(as showed), why a single process within that pod consume more than 10%. This does not make sense to me. I added the screenshot of my top/htop result.